# Rails how to remove obj from that have certain combination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Example I have this array:

```
@packages = ["2", ["4", "2", "1"], "4", ["4","2"], ["5", "6"]]
```

`2` and `4` may not be composed

There for `["4", "2", "1"]` and `["4,"2"]` should be removed from the array

How should it be done?

So the output would be: `@packages = ["2", "4", ["5", "6"]]`

2 and 4 is just an example. And the number of numbers vary also.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to ask... What is the general form of your input and your expected output?

Comment: The numbers 2 and 4 in the array may not be together and any combination of those should be removed. I have written the output.

Comment: I still think it would be faster to spend some time learning the language instead of waiting for answers to questions like these--seriously, an afternoon of study would save you a ton of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove arrays, that have at least 2 elements in common with given do:

```
@packages = ["2", ["4", "2", "1"], "4", ["4","2"], ["3", "2"]]
@opposites = ["2", "4"]

@packages.reject! { |p| p.is_a?(Array) && (@opposites & p).size >= 2 }
```

After this `@packages => ["2", "4", ["3", "2"]]`

Comment: The only problem is that if @opposites were ["2", "4", "9"] it would only remove a 100% match and not ["2", "4"] you can see it here http://pastie.org/3220682

Comment: I still don't get what you want to achieve if not '100% match'.

Comment: Example the numbers that may not be together is ["2", "4", "9"]. Then should any array be removed that have these compinations: ["2", "4"] and ["2", "9"] and ["2", "4", "9"]. Think if it like a has_one relation ship. The arrays in the array may only has_one of the numbers 2, 4 and 9

Comment: So remove arrays that have at least 2 elements in common with opposites? Editer answer does this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see if an Array has both `"2"` and `"4"` is to use [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-26) (i.e. set intersection):

```
@packages.reject { |a| a.is_a?(Array) && (a & [ '2', '4' ]).length == 2 }
```

For example:

```
>> @packages = ["2", ["4", "2", "1"], "4", ["4","2"], ["5", "6"], ["1", "2"], ["4", "11"], ["2", "2", "4"]]
=> ["2", ["4", "2", "1"], "4", ["4", "2"], ["5", "6"], ["1", "2"], ["4", "11"], ["2", "2", "4"]]
>> @packages.reject { |a| a.is_a?(Array) && (a & [ '2', '4' ]).length == 2 }
=> ["2", "4", ["5", "6"], ["1", "2"], ["4", "11"]]
```

If you have your reject list in a separate array then the above generalizes quite easily:

```
rejects = %w(2 4)
@packages.reject { |a| a.is_a?(Array) && (a & rejects).length == rejects.length }
```

You'd just have to make sure that `rejects` didn't have any duplicates but you can always add a [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) if you're not sure if `rejects` has duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you question is not entirely clear. If you just want to remove the Array elements of the main array then you can do.

```
@packages.reject{|element| element.is_a?(Array)}
```

Comment: I don´t want to remove all arrays in the array. Just those arrays that have a compination of 2 and 4